# Move existing join table data to another join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, rails-migrations

I have a rails app that has a pretty broken table relation that I am trying to clean up.

Currently I have a Product and a Person and between them are three different join tables: artists, authors and cover_artists.

I am trying to migrate the data from the three existing join tables into a new join table called creators. The new creators join includes a role column.

This is my migration file for moving the data from one of the three joins into the new one.
However when I run this I am not seeing any of the data in the new table.

```
def up
  execute <<-SQL
    UPDATE creators
    SET product_id = products_artists.product_id,
      person_id = products_artists.person_id,
      role = 'artist'
    FROM products_artists
  SQL
end

def down
  execute <<-SQL
    UPDATE products_artists
    SET product_id = creators.product_id,
      person_id = creators.person_id
    FROM creators
    WHERE creators.role = 'artist'
  SQL
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, I was looking for an insert not an update.

```
def up
  execute <<-SQL
    INSERT INTO creators (product_id, person_id, role, created_at, updated_at)
    SELECT product_id, person_id, 'artist', current_timestamp, current_timestamp
    FROM products_artists
  SQL
end

def down
  execute <<-SQL
    INSERT INTO products_artists (product_id, person_id)
    SELECT product_id, person_id
    FROM creators
    WHERE role = 'artist'
  SQL
end
```